# Having a problem to run .compile() on my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I have problem with using .compile() after building a simple Sequential model with keras.

The error type I got:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

By the way, I run the code on Colab and it works. The problem is that the code doesn't work on my system, and I'm using anaconda Jupyter notebook.

the code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    model = keras.Sequential(
   [
       layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name ="layer1"),
       layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name ="layer2"),
       layers.Dense(4, name="layer3")
   ])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   2725         # Go through tensor shapes to get int64-if-needed semantics
-> 2726         shape = constant_op._tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function(
   2727             tensor_shape.TensorShape(shape))

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function(s, dtype, name, as_ref)
    356     name = "shape_as_tensor"
--> 357   return constant(s_list, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    358 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    261   """
--> 262   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    263                         allow_broadcast=True)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    270   if ctx.executing_eagerly():
--> 271     t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    272     if shape is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96 
---> 97   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name(), dtype)
     98 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-3bc1e703d8ff> in <module>
----> 1 model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optim, metrics=metrics)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, **kwargs)
    327 
    328       self.optimizer = self._get_optimizer(optimizer)
--> 329       self.compiled_loss = compile_utils.LossesContainer(
    330           loss, loss_weights, output_names=self.output_names)
    331       self.compiled_metrics = compile_utils.MetricsContainer(

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py in __init__(self, losses, loss_weights, output_names)
    118     self._loss_weights = loss_weights
    119     self._per_output_metrics = None  # Per-output losses become metrics.
--> 120     self._loss_metric = metrics_mod.Mean(name='loss')  # Total loss.
    121     self._built = False
    122 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in __init__(self, name, dtype)
    468       dtype: (Optional) data type of the metric result.
    469     """
--> 470     super(Mean, self).__init__(
    471         reduction=metrics_utils.Reduction.WEIGHTED_MEAN, name=name, dtype=dtype)
    472 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in __init__(self, reduction, name, dtype)
    305     self.reduction = reduction
    306     with ops.init_scope():
--> 307       self.total = self.add_weight(
    308           'total', initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer)
    309       if reduction in [metrics_utils.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, aggregation, synchronization, initializer, dtype)
    274       synchronization = tf_variables.VariableSynchronization.ON_WRITE
    275 
--> 276     return super(Metric, self).add_weight(
    277         name=name,
    278         shape=shape,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint, partitioner, use_resource, synchronization, aggregation, **kwargs)
    558         caching_device = None
    559 
--> 560     variable = self._add_variable_with_custom_getter(
    561         name=name,
    562         shape=shape,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _add_variable_with_custom_getter(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, getter, overwrite, **kwargs_for_getter)
    736         initializer = checkpoint_initializer
    737         shape = None
--> 738     new_variable = getter(
    739         name=name,
    740         shape=shape,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in make_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer, trainable, caching_device, validate_shape, constraint, use_resource, collections, synchronization, aggregation, partitioner)
    127   # can remove the V1.
    128   variable_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(shape)
--> 129   return tf_variables.VariableV1(
    130       initial_value=init_val,
    131       name=name,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    257   def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    258     if cls is VariableV1:
--> 259       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    260     elif cls is Variable:
    261       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in _variable_v1_call(cls, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, expected_shape, import_scope, constraint, use_resource, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
    203     if aggregation is None:
    204       aggregation = VariableAggregation.NONE
--> 205     return previous_getter(
    206         initial_value=initial_value,
    207         trainable=trainable,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in getter(**kwargs)
     64 
     65   def getter(**kwargs):
---> 66     return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
     67 
     68   return getter

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in creator(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2560     def creator(next_creator, **kwargs):
   2561       _require_strategy_scope_strategy(strategy)
-> 2562       return next_creator(**kwargs)
   2563 
   2564     self._var_creator_scope = variable_scope.variable_creator_scope(creator)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in <lambda>(**kwargs)
    196                         shape=None):
    197     """Call on Variable class. Useful to force the signature."""
--> 198     previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
    199     for _, getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    200       previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py in default_variable_creator(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2582   if use_resource:
   2583     distribute_strategy = kwargs.get("distribute_strategy", None)
-> 2584     return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
   2585         initial_value=initial_value,
   2586         trainable=trainable,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    261       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    262     else:
--> 263       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    264 
    265 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def, import_scope, constraint, distribute_strategy, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
   1421       self._init_from_proto(variable_def, import_scope=import_scope)
   1422     else:
-> 1423       self._init_from_args(
   1424           initial_value=initial_value,
   1425           trainable=trainable,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, distribute_strategy, shape)
   1565           with ops.name_scope("Initializer"), device_context_manager(None):
   1566             initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(
-> 1567                 initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,
   1568                 name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
   1569           if shape is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py in <lambda>()
    119         (type(init_ops.Initializer), type(init_ops_v2.Initializer))):
    120       initializer = initializer()
--> 121     init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)
    122     variable_dtype = dtype.base_dtype
    123   if use_resource is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype, partition_info)
    112     if dtype is None:
    113       dtype = self.dtype
--> 114     return array_ops.zeros(shape, dtype)
    115 
    116   def get_config(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   2675 
   2676   def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
-> 2677     tensor = fun(*args, **kwargs)
   2678     tensor._is_zeros_tensor = True
   2679     return tensor

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   2728       except (TypeError, ValueError):
   2729         # Happens when shape is a list with tensor elements
-> 2730         shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtypes.int32)
   2731     if not shape._shape_tuple():
   2732       shape = reshape(shape, [-1])  # Ensure it's a vector

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1339 
   1340     if ret is None:
-> 1341       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1342 
   1343     if ret is NotImplemented:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    320                                          as_ref=False):
    321   _ = as_ref
--> 322   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    323 
    324 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    260     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    261   """
--> 262   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    263                         allow_broadcast=True)
    264 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    269   ctx = context.context()
    270   if ctx.executing_eagerly():
--> 271     t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    272     if shape is None:
    273       return t

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
     96 
---> 97   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name(), dtype)
     98 
     99 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

​
```

Comment: Try running the cells 126, 127 and 128 again, respectively.

Comment: Please never add code as images, only as text.

Comment: I did run the cells respectively. Nothing change

Comment: Again, put all code and error messages as text, we only have partial information and it is very bad practice to use code images. Note that the traceback is incomplete, meaning we cannot really help you until you provide all necessary information.

Comment: Sorry, if I put the code as an image

Comment: Also, I add a note. Thanks

Comment: this code runs successfully. try restarting kernel maybe some local variables have overridden.

Comment: You now removed the error message... sigh...

Comment: just add the error

Comment: Hi!  It was throwing  some errors  in my local machine then  checked  your code in  Jupyter notebook `after  updating  anaconda  using "conda update conda" and installing "Tensorflow" from  the  respective environment in anaconda console  instead of installing particular version using "pip " command `, Issue is getting resolved after that  . Yes , In Colab, its working fine.